# Can I change SparkContext.appName on the fly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I know I can use [`SparkConf.set('spark.app.name',...)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkConf) to set `appName` *before* creating the `SparkContext`.

However, I want to change the name of the application as it progresses, i.e., after  `SparkContext` has been created.

Alas, setting `sc.appName` does not change how the job is shown by [`yarn application -list`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#application).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not possible: any update to the `sparkConf`, including `spark.app.name`, is only taken into account before the instance of SparkConf is used to instanciate a SparkContext:

> Note that once a SparkConf object is passed to Spark, it is cloned and can no longer be modified by the user. Spark does not support modifying the configuration at runtime.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkConf

Comment: Note that I am not asking about changing `SparkConf` but about modifying the `SparkContext.appName` directly.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible, `sc.appName` is implemented as `val appName = conf.get("spark.app.name") `, which of course cannot be assigned, and any modification via `sc.getconf.setXYZ` ) will have not effect either since getConf is `def getConf: SparkConf = conf.clone()`. 

Once the context is created, the config is considered immutable and communicated as such to all concerned parties.